# scrolling animation with css3

Tags: css, animation

im doing some animation with css3 using this example:

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#

I have made Jquery code to provide that animations appears by scrolling. When i do the animation just with one div everything is going right, but something is going wrong when i try to apply the same animation for two divs with the same class, the first rectangle is getting animated but not happens with the second; Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 

 <style>

  body {
     height: 2200px;
  }
  #objeto {
    /* modifique la posición para que se vea en la caja de stacksnippet */
   
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .slideUp {
    animation-name: slideUp;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  @keyframes slideUp {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65% {
      transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80% {
      transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95% {
      transform: translateY(2%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
 </style>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  li{
   color: black;
  }
  .foo{
   background-color: yellow;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="objeto" style="position: relative;
    top: 100px;"></div>

 <div id="objeto"></div> 

 



 <script>


 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#objeto').each(function() {
      var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
      var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

     console.log(imagePos, topOfWindow);
     if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
       $(this).addClass("slideUp");
     }
   });
 });

 /*$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('ul').each(function( ) {
      $(this).css("background-color","blue")
      
   });
 });*/

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can make the test. If you put `$('#objeto').length` it returns 1, even if you have 5 elements with same id. Duplicated ids in the same html page is a bad practice and it causes a lot of problems. This solves with the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should use class instead of ID. since ID is unique (https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class).

Simply change the code to:

```
.objeto {
      /* modifique la posición para que se vea en la caja de stacksnippet */

      width: 30%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

And

```
<div class="objeto" style="position: relative;
      top: 100px;"></div>

<div class="objeto"></div>
```

And

```
$('.objeto').each(function() {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
```